# TypeError: scalar() got multiple values for argument 'name'

Tags: python, typeerror, scalar

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-af22e6723577> in <module>()
     19         with tf.name_scope("summaries"):
     20             avg=tf.div(update_total,tf.cast(increment_step,tf.float32),name="average")
---> 21             tf.summary.scalar(b'Output',output,name="output_summary")
     22             tf.summary.scalar(b'Sum of outputs over time',update_total,name="total_summary")
     23             tf.summary.scalar(b'Average of outputs over time',avg,name="average_summary")

TypeError: scalar() got multiple values for argument 'name'
```

Answer (score 3):

See the docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/scalar

> scalar(
>       name,
>       tensor,
>       collections=None,
>       family=None )

The first argument is the `name` argument, hence the call 
`tf.summary.scalar(b'Output', output, name="output_summary")` assigns both `b'Output'` and `'output_summary'` to `name`.

You have the exact issue with the next 2 calls to `scalar`.

Comment: I got u. The problem had solved and thank you so much.